# Can I stop rollerblading?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

Rollerblading around in X and Y is a fast way to travel, but I've found it really difficult to maneuver around tight spaces sometimes. It would be nice if I could register them to turn them off, or use <kbd>B</kbd> to force myself to run instead. Is there any way to quickly and temporarily disable rollerblading?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Rollerblading is only when you use the analog stick. Moving with the D-pad switches you to walking and running (with B held down).

If you are using the Dowsing Machine, you will not use your rollerblades and can still use the analog stick to move. You can still run by holding B though.

Comment: But is there anyway to not rollerblade but use the analog stick anyway?

Comment: Not that I know of.